# Creating an View without the navigation Item bar in Xcode

Tags: cocoa-touch, view, uinavigationcontroller, swift, xcode6

I am trying to connect a new empty View(homeScreen) from a ViewController (loginScreen) using Xcode 6 Beta 4 and Swift. A button triggers the segue to the homeScreen View. The problem is that when I add the segue, my blank/empty homeScreen View magically gets a Navigation Item Bar on top of the view.

You can see that without the segue my homeScreen View its empty:
[image: Without the Segue]

After the segue it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, Xcode inserts the Navigation Item Bar on top (grey rectangle). I would like to know how to get rid of it or how to create an empty View that remains empty even after assigning a segue to it.

Thank you so much for your help!

Cheers!

---

UPDATE: My goal is to create a navigation bar kind of like the one Facebook implements in its' iOS app. On top have the search bar and maybe some more icons. Does anybody know how to do that? I tried to hide the Navigation bar by selecting my view controller and in the Attributes inspector setting the "Top Bar" attribute to none, but it does not work. Any suggestions?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Does *loginScreen* is inside a *UINavigationController*? If it is, the new showed view controller (*homeScreen*) is supposed to be in the navigation controller too, and thus it has a navigation bar by default.

You can hide it if you want, but then you have to find an alternative way to navigate in your navigation controller.

Otherwise you can present the *homeScreen* modally changing the type of segue to "Present Modally".

For more details on view controller presentation see [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) plus some updates in iOS8 (WWDC session: View Controller Advancement in iOS8).

[image]

EDIT: To implement the FB-like navigation bar I would customize the UINavigationController bar:

- read this [AppCoda tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/) about customizing the bar
- to add a search bar use the code like:

> ```
> let searchBar = UISearchBar()
> ... 
> self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBar
> ```

Comment: I do not know if the loginScreen is inside an UINavigationController or not. My loginScreen is connected to a UINAvigationController, and then it has a segue to the homeScreen UIViewController. Does that mean that it is inside a UINavigationController? Also, please read the update to my post since I explicitly explain what I am trying to achieve. Maybe you have some other advice for me? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Yes, it means you are definitely inside a UINavigationController. See my edit for the nav bar.

Comment: I have my own UISearchBar in my storyboard. I have an outlet in my homeScreenViewController for it (homeSearchBar) and I also inherit the UISearchBarDelegate in my class. That being said, I have to say I have no idea how to set it up. Is titleView (used in the last line of your edit) declared by you? Or is it a property that you are accessing?

I get that I need to use this line of code: self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"appcoda-logo.png"]]; and instead of setting an image I should set my UISearchBar. Any advice? Thank your for your time!

Answer (score 0):

**This is because the segue is a "push" segue ("Show (e.g. push)") from a View controller that is already included in a Navigation controller. Therefore, it is put in the stack of views of this Navigation Controller, and therefore receives a navigation bar.**

If you don't want a navigation bar, then use either a modal segue ("Present modally"), or a custom segue.

Same thing if you need a different navigation Bar (not linked to the first Navigation Controller). You can perfectly have a modal segue leading to a UIViewController, which is embedded in its OWN navigation controller (or having only a navigation bar). Have a look in the menu: "Edit / Embed / Navigation controller".